# Issues with Deploy test agent with error Cannot find path 'C:\TestAgent2017Setup\vstf_testagent.exe' because it does not exist

Tags: tfs

Deploy test agent fails with the following error, Test agent location is not specified:

Details : 'The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Cannot find path 'C:\TestAgent2017Setup\vstf_testagent.exe' because it does not exist.'. For troubleshooting, refer https://aka.ms/remotevstest.

Following error is reported if the Test agent location is specified with the following value "2018-01-04T06:58:26.3880275Z agentLocation      "C:\TestAgent\vstf_testagent.exe", the executable is pre downloaded and copied to "C:\TestAgent" path.

Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Exception calling "Start" with "1" argument(s): "'agentlocation' is not a valid path. Ensure that the account with which build agent is running has access to this share."

The agent location path specified from the shared path with all the necessary privileges also fails stating " Cannot find path 'C:\TestAgent2017Setup\vstf_testagent.exe'"

Deploy TestAget version: 2*(Preview)

TFS 2017 update 1 on premise.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Yet to upgrade the TFS version, as we are in process of moving from on-premise to VSTS, will update asap. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using *v2 agent deployment step* and deploy 2017 test agent. It's a known issue on TFS 2017 update 1 on premise.

This issue is **fixed in  TFS2017 Update 2.** You could upgrade your TFS server version.

> Alternatively, you can patch the task in your TFS from latest master
>   using [tfx-cli](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli).
>
> PR for ref: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/pull/3707/files

More details of the issue and workaround,  please take a look at [this similar one](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3922) in GitHub.